# Что означает данная запись

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, объявление

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int b[10];
    int ( *a )[ 10 ];       // эта
    a = b;                  // error
    a[ 0 ] = new int;       // error
    a = new int;            // error

}
```

Пытаюсь методом подбора понять что это и **как это используется**.

Comment: в подобных непонятных случаях можно пользоватся таким сервисом [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28+*a+%29%5B+10+%5D%3B). Он хорошо подсказывает.

Comment: Спасибо, сохранил себе в закладки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы проще было понять запись

```
int ( *a )[ 10 ];
```

можно ввести определение алиаса для массива

```
typedef int T[10];

T *a;
```

то есть объекты, которые может адресовать указатель, представляют собой целочисленные массивы из десяти элементов.

Если вы хотите, например, чтобы этот указатель адресовал такой массив, вы можете написать

```
typedef int T[10];

T b;

T *a;
a = &b;
```

Тогда выражение `*a` или `a[0]` представляет собой массив `b`

Например, вы можете написать

```
typedef int T[10];

T b;

T *a;
a = &b;

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) a[0][i] = i;
```

Если хотите динамически выделить массив, то вам следует записать

```
typedef int T[10];

T *a;
a = new T[1];
```

Это эквивалентно следующему фрагменту кода

```
int ( *a )[10];

a = new int[1][10];
```

То есть такой указатель используется обычно при работе с двумерными массивами. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 2;
    const size_t N = 10;

    int b[M][N] =
    {
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
        { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 }
    };

    for ( int ( *a )[N] = b; a != b + M; ++a )
    {
        for ( int x : *a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Можно без указателя: `for (auto&& row : b) for (auto x : row) cout << x << ' ';`

Comment: @jfs Я преднамеренно использовал указатель.

Comment: я пониманию (это к вопросу о мотивации: можно использовать указатель, но не нужно).

Answer (score 6):

Формально это - указатель на массив из 10 `int`.

Так что присваивать нужно как

```
a = &b;
```

Если хотите использовать для присваивания элемента - то

```
(*a)[0] = 12;  // Присваивание b[0] = 12
```

Если же вы имеете в виду массив массивов по 10 элементов, то

```
a[0][3] = 15;  // Присваивание третьему элементу первого массива
               // по адресу a значение 15 - то же, что и b[3] = 15;
```

Ну, а последнее... например, так:

```
using arr = int[10];
a = new arr[1];
```

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите как это используется - ведь статический массив передаётся по ссылке и не копируется. Когда может пригодиться указатель?

Comment: Ну, придумать, наверное, можно... но в C++ вообще куда удобнее использовать `vector`. В принципе, вот - двумерный массив :) Объявляем как внизу в ответе - что-то вроде `a = new arr[5]`, и получаем двумерный массив...